# How can I exchange the background color of two buttons with each other?

Tags: java, android

I need to make a method so that, when clicking on a first button, its id and background color are saved, and when pressing a second button, they change the background color between them. How can i do that?

I had thought something like this:

```
public void changeColor(View v){
    clicks = clicks++;
    if (clicks == 1){
        button1 = findViewById(v.getId());
        color1 = button1.getBackground();
    }
    if (clicks == 2){
        button2 = findViewById(v.getId());
        color2 = button2.getBackground();
        button1.setBackground(color2);
        button2.setBackground(color1);
    }
    if (clicks == 2){
        clicks = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Incase of button you type boton so it can't work of use 
boton ensure this line begin of your code
button1 = boton1
button2 = boton3
and also import java.awt package in your code

public void changeColor(View v) {
clicks = clicks++;
if (clicks == 1){
    button1 = findViewById(v.getId());
    color1 = button1.getBackground();
}
else if (clicks == 2) {
    button2 = findViewById(v.getId());
    color2 = button2.getBackground();
    button1.setBackground(color2);
    button2.setBackground(color1);
    clicks = 0;
 }
```